# Docusign - HTTP/1.1://docusignapp2.herokuapp.com?op=webhook :: Error - Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to get envelope status from docusign connect demo environement. Used the below link and deployed in heroku

https://github.com/docusign/recipe-010-webhook-java

When I try to send the document and waiting for updates I am not getting it in the webhook URL I am using

I am seeing the error log

`HTTP/1.1://docusignapp2.herokuapp.com?op=webhook :: Error - Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid`

Can you please help

Comment: Hey Anand, welcome to stackoverflow! You should clarify in your question what you have done so far and which steps are needed to recreate your problem. Especially what kind of document you're trying to send and which URI you are using.

Comment: I am trying to get the docusign connect to send the updates to the url  https://docusignapp2.herokuapp.com?op=webhook

Comment: I have deployed the sample code available in https://github.com/docusign/recipe-010-webhook-java and sent a  document for signature thought the deployed application.

Comment: Logged into docusign and voided the document and expected the webhook to recive the update from docusign but no response is coming on the changed document status

Comment: On checking the error messages in docusign sandbox account I could see the error message as "HTTP/1.1://docusignapp2.herokuapp.com?op=webhook :: Error - Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid."

Comment: Let me know if any other information is needed. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

The URL [`docusignapp2.herokuapp.com/?op=webhook`](https://docusignapp2.herokuapp.com/?op=webhook) appears to work. And when it complains, that `The URI scheme is not valid`, this most likely means you have to use `https` instead of `http` as the URI scheme. `HTTP/1.1` actually could be both protocols; therefore one can only assume.

Answer (score 0):

That DocuSign webhook example you're trying is obsolete and should not be used. I'm having it removed.

Instead, we recommend using an asynchronous queuing pattern to receive and process event notifications. In addition to higher reliability, this pattern also enables notifications to be received behind the firewall with no changes (eg holes) needed in the firewall.

See the connect- series of [code examples.](https://github.com/docusign?q=in%3Aname%20connect-&type=&language=)

For Java, for AWS, here's the [listener example](https://github.com/docusign/connect-node-listener-aws) and the [Java worker example](https://github.com/docusign/connect-java-worker-aws). There are also examples for Azure and Google Cloud.

The AWS costs are $0.00 per month for a million notifications a month.